# remove hyperlinks in libre office

Tags: libreoffice-writer

How can I remove hyperlinks in LibreOffice documents? The remove-hyperlink entry in the context-menu isn't working. It's LibreOffice 3.5.4.2 shipped with Ubuntu Precise Pangolin.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: might sound silly, did you had the text selected ?

Comment: I've installed LibreOffice 3.6 in Ubuntu 12.04. In that, just right-clicking on a link has a `remove hyperlink` option that works. Do you at least get a tooltip that goes something like this: `ctrl+click to open hyperlink` when you hover over a link? I'm asking because if you don't see that tooltip, it may indicate that, for whatever reason, Writer is not recognizing the hyperlink in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Right-clicking on the object and selecting 'Remove hyperlink' only seems to remove hyperlink data for some types of objects.

When the above fails to remove hyperlink-ish behavior, right-click on the object and then select 'Clear Direct Formatting'.

If push comes to shove, and the text is all that's desired, right-click on the object, select 'Edit hyperlink', and then cut/paste the desired text from the hyperlink dialog window. Note that this can also be accomplished by selecting the object, copying the object (Edit->Copy), and then pasting the unformatted text of the object (Edit->Paste Special and then select 'Unformatted text').

Finally, if you're handy with a text editor, the hyperlink can be removed directly. Save the document as a "Flat XML" file (use Save As and specify the format). Then, open the document in a "plain text" editor (e.g., emacs or vi) and search for the XML element with the attribute `xlink:href` where the value is the troublesome hyperlink. At this point, you can remove the corresponding XML element completely.